# System "Read-Only" log file?

Tags: 14.04, log, read-only

This has happened *randomly* on a couple of restarts I've been googling to figure out where the log file is that would show what is causing this to happen as it doesn't happen every time.

EDIT:

log file contents https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdLtz.jpg

wasn't sure how I was going to copy paste they are in order of bootlog, syslog error, failed

kernel and syslog critical returned nothing

EDIT2:

Added dmesg not sure if the two I/O lines are errors or if it only out put errors sorry :/

Comment: No weird things in those logs. Nothing that would cause a read only system, Care to do the fsck -N sda?

Comment: fsck -N sda outputs 
`[/sbin/fsck.ext4 (1) -- /l fsck.ext4 sda /dev/mapper/CAC_VG-CAC_LV`
`[/sbin/fsck.ext4 (1) -- /boot] fsck.ext4 sda /dev/sda1`

Answer (score 2):

All log files are in `/var/log/`.

Important log files that might contain what you are looking for:

- boot.log
- kernel.log
- syslog

Use commandline or log viewer from the GUI to search for words like "error", "critical", "failed". Edit your question and copy/paste results of these in it or use google to search these notice.

The command `dmesg` also will show you info on your system.

"I/O error" is another to search for. A failing hard disk will end up with I/O errors and that would cause the filesystem to randomly mount read only.

`fsck -N {device}`  does a filesystem check without actually changing something (aka. a dry run)